# How to make a calculated field that will be true for each row if one row is true in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data table with column ***Status*** and ***Extract Name*** and some other columns. I want to create a calculated field whose value will be true for each row if one row is true. To be clear, if there is a row where the ***Status*** is "In progress" and ***Extract Name*** is "A" I want the other rows for which this is not valid to be true (I mean that column ***Calculation*** should be true for each row), not just for that row. The picture shows that table where I was able to make only that row true. [image: Picture]

This is the code:

```
IF [Status]="In Progress" AND [Extract Name]="A"
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
END
```

How do I modify that code to get what I want, to make all rows true if there is one row that matches this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
IF
{MAX(IF [Status]="In Progress" AND [Extract Name]="A"
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END)} >0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

If you want a demonstration, please add some sample data

Comment: Thank you! That is what I want

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Or, something like this.
IF [Status]="In Progress" OR [Status]="Completed" AND [Extract Name]="A"
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
END

The OR operator would make all the rows True. The AND operator may be omitted.

Comment: That won't work as the OP desires it to work